# Why does derivative of sum(u) result in vector of 1s?

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, neural-networks

I came across these formulas (please see attached) in a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01528.pdf). Could you please explain why the derivative of *sum*(**u**) where **u** is the dot product of vectors **w** and **x** results in vector of **1**s? Thanks
[derivative of sum of dot product between two vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CRvI.jpg)

Comment: Isn't that a tensor product, rather than a dot product?

Comment: @JohnDoe, I'm not sure, but that's what the paper says "The dot product w.x is just the summation of the element-wise multiplication of the elements..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum() function itself is a dot product, i.e. 
$$y = {\rm sum}(u) = 1^Tu$$
Therefore its differential and derivative are
$$dy = 1^Tdu \quad\implies\quad\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = 1^T$$

Comment: Wow! A huge THANKYOU!